# Data cannot key in Into database

Tags: php

**ERROR :**

> Notice: Undefined index: cawangan_ppk in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\eselenggaraMada\USER\laporanrosakU.php on line 62

**Define Variables :**

```
$tarikhisi = $nama = $namapelapor =  $bahagian = $cawangan_ppk = $kategorirosak = $jenisrosak = $nosiri = $ringkasanrosak = "";
$tarikhisi_err = $nama_err = $namapelapor_err =  $bahagian_err = $cawangan_ppk_err = $kategorirosak_err = $jenisrosak_err = $nosiri_err = $ringkasanrosak_err = "";
```

**Line 62 :**

```
$input_cawangan_ppk = trim($_POST["cawangan_ppk"]);
```

```
if(empty($input_cawangan_ppk)){
        $cawangan_ppk_err = "Please enter an Cawangan.";     
    } else{
        $cawangan_ppk = $input_cawangan_ppk;
    }
```

**CODE :**

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: loginU.php");
    exit;
}
?>

<?php

// Include config file
require_once "configU.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$tarikhisi = $nama = $namapelapor =  $bahagian = $cawangan_ppk = $kategorirosak = $jenisrosak = $nosiri = $ringkasanrosak = "";

$tarikhisi_err = $nama_err = $namapelapor_err =  $bahagian_err = $cawangan_ppk_err = $kategorirosak_err = $jenisrosak_err = $nosiri_err = $ringkasanrosak_err = "";


// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] = "POST"){

    // Validate tarikh
    $input_tarikhisi  = trim($_POST["tarikhisi"]);
    if(empty($input_tarikhisi)){
        $tarikhisi_err = "Masukkan Tarikh.";     
    } else{
        $tarikhisi  = $input_tarikhisi;
    }

 // Validate nama
    $input_nama  = trim($_POST["nama"]);
    if(empty($input_nama)){
        $nama_err = "Masukkan Nama.";     
    } else{
        $nama = $input_nama;
    }

 // Validate nama pelapor
    $input_namapelapor = trim($_POST["namapelapor"]);
    if(empty($input_namapelapor)){
        $namapelapor_err = "Please enter a name.";
    } elseif(!filter_var($input_namapelapor, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))){
        $namapelapor_err = "Please enter a valid name.";
    } else{
        $namapelapor = $input_namapelapor;
    }

     // Validate bahagian
    $input_bahagian = trim($_POST["bahagian"]);
    if(empty($input_bahagian)){
        $bahagian_err = "Please enter an Bahagian.";     
    } else{
        $bahagian = $input_bahagian;
    }

    // Validate cawangan
    $input_cawangan_ppk = trim($_POST["cawangan_ppk"]);
    if(empty($input_cawangan_ppk)){
        $cawangan_ppk_err = "Please enter an Cawangan.";     
    } else{
        $cawangan_ppk = $input_cawangan_ppk;
    }


   // Validate kategorirosak
    $input_kategorirosak = trim($_POST["kategorirosak"]);
    if(empty($input_kategorirosak)){
        $kategorirosak_err = "Please enter an kategorirosak.";     
    } else{
        $kategorirosak = $input_kategorirosak;
    }

    // Validate Jenis Kerosakkan
    $input_jenisrosak = trim($_POST["jenisrosak"]);
    if(empty($input_jenisrosak)){
        $jenisrosak_err = "Please enter an Jenis Kerosakkan.";     
    } else{
        $jenisrosak = $input_jenisrosak;
    }

     // Validate No.Siri
    $input_nosiri = trim($_POST["nosiri"]);
    if(empty($input_nosiri)){
        $nosiri_err = "Please enter an No Siri.";     
    } else{
        $nosiri = $input_nosiri;
    }

    // Validate Ringkasan Kerosakkan
    $input_ringkasanrosak = trim($_POST["ringkasanrosak"]);
    if(empty($input_ringkasanrosak)){
        $ringkasanrosak_err = "Please enter an Ringkasan Kerosakkan.";     
    } else{
        $ringkasanrosak = $input_ringkasanrosak;
    }

     // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($tarikhisi_err) && empty($nama_err) && empty($namapelapor_err) && empty($bahagian_err) && empty($cawangan_ppk_err) && empty($kategorirosak_err) && empty($jenisrosak_err)
     && empty($nosiri_err) && empty($ringkasanrosak_err)){
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO laporankerosakkan (tarikhisi , nama , namapelapor , bahagian , cawangan_ppk , kategorirosak , jenisrosak , nosiri , ringkasanrosak) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $param_tarikhisi, $param_nama, $param_namapelapor , $param_bahagian, $param_cawangan_ppk, $param_kategorirosak, $param_jenisrosak,
                $param_nosiri,  $param_ringkasanrosak);

            // Set parameters
            $param_tarikhisi = $tarikhisi;
            $param_nama = $nama;
            $param_namapelapor = $namapelapor;
            $param_bahagian = $bahagian;
            $param_cawangan_ppk = $cawangan_ppk;
            $param_kategorirosak = $kategorirosak;
            $param_jenisrosak = $jenisrosak;
            $param_nosiri = $nosiri;
            $param_ringkasanrosak = $ringkasanrosak;





            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                // Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header ("location: homeU.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later...";

            }

        }
           // Close statement
        $stmt->close();
    }

    // Close connection
    $mysqli->close();
}

var_dump($_POST);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

   <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper{
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>

  <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="..\image/logo1.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\style/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/image_gallery.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="..\style\3css.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style\about.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="..\style\top.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\style/form.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ADUAN KEROSAKKAN</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
    </style>
</head>

<?php

// Include config file
require_once "configU.php";
 ?>

<body>
  <center>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Hi, <b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?></b>. Welcome to e-selenggaraMada.</h1>
    </div>
    <tr>

<div>
  </div>
</div>
<ul>
            <li><a  href="homeU.php">UTAMA</a></li>
            <li><a  class="active" href="laporanrosakU.php">ADUAN KEROSAKKAN</a></li>
            <li><a  href="senarailaporU.php">SENARAI LAPORAN</a></li>
            <li><a  href="about.php">HUBUNGI</a></li>
            <li><a  href="carianU.php">CARI</a></li>

        </ul>
        <iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i628bi4j/n3832/tlmy40/fn7/fs20/fc33f/tct/pct/tt0/th2" frameborder="0" width="389" height="30" allowTransparency="true" align="right"></iframe>


        </p>
<!--Form section-->
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h2>Borang Aduan Kerosakkan</h2>
                    </div>

                    <p><h3>Masukkan Maklumat.</h3></p>
                    &nbsp;
                      <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">

                      <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($tarikhisi_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>Tarikh</label>
                            <input type="text" name="tarikhisi" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $tarikhisi; ?>">
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $tarikhisi_err;?></span>
                        </div>



                        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($nama_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>Nama</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nama" class="form-control" readonly value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?>">
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $nama_err;?></span>
                        </div>



                        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($namapelapor_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>Nama Pelapor</label>
                            <input type="text" name="namapelapor" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $namapelapor; ?>">
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $namapelapor_err;?></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($bahagian_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>Bahagian</label>                           
                         <select class="form-control" type="text" name="bahagian" id="bahagian" maxlength="12" placeholder="bahagian" required />
                                            <option value="">-Sila Pilih-</option>
                                            <?php
                                                $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM bahagian ");  
                                                while (($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) != false) 
                                                echo '<option value="', $data['nama'],'">', $data['nama'],'</option>'
                                            ?>
                           </select>
                        </div>


                         <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($cawangan_ppk_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>Cawangan/PPK</label>
                             <select class="form-control" type="text" name="cawangan" id="cawangan" maxlength="12" placeholder="bahagian" required />
                                            <option value="">-Sila Pilih-</option>
                                            <?php
                                                $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM cawangan_ppk ");  
                                                while (($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) != false) 
                                                echo '<option value="', $data['nama'],'">', $data['nama'],'</option>'
                                            ?>
                           </select>
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $cawangan_ppk_err;?></span>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($kategorirosak_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>kategorirosak</label>
                             <select class="form-control" type="text" name="kategorirosak" id="kategorirosak" maxlength="12" placeholder="kategorirosak" required />
                                            <option value="">-Sila Pilih-</option>
                                            <?php
                                                $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM kategorirosak ");  
                                                while (($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) != false) 
                                                echo '<option value="', $data['nama'],'">', $data['nama'],'</option>'
                                            ?>
                           </select>
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $kategorirosak_err;?></span>
                        </div>


                         <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($jenisrosak_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>Jenis Kerosakkan</label>
                            <select class="form-control" type="text" name="jenisrosak" id="jenisrosak" maxlength="12" placeholder="jenisrosak" required />
                                            <option value="">-Sila Pilih-</option>
                                            <?php
                                                $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM jenisrosak ");  
                                                while (($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) != false) 
                                                echo '<option value="', $data['nama'],'">', $data['nama'],'</option>'
                                            ?>
                           </select>
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $jenisrosak_err;?></span>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($nosiri_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>No.Siri Peralatan</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nosiri" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $nosiri; ?>">
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $nosiri_err;?></span>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($ringkasanrosak_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>Ringkasan Kerosakkan</label>
                            <input type="text" name="ringkasanrosak" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $ringkasanrosak; ?>">
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $ringkasanrosak_err;?></span>
                        </div>


                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                        <a href="homeU.php" class="btn btn-default">Batal Aduan</a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>

&nbsp;<center>
   <a href="resetU-password.php" class="btn btn-warning">TUKAR KATA LALUAN</a>
        <a href="logoutU.php" class="btn btn-danger">LOG KELUAR</a>

</body>
</html>
```

*any help are really appreciate, Thank You So Much*

Comment: That error means that there is no `cawangan_ppk`  in the array.

Comment: there is no cawangan_ppk in your form thats why when you submit returns error

Comment: You don't have a field that is named `cawangan_ppk` in your form

Comment: Post the whole script so that we'll able to analyze what is wrong.

Comment: There just like comment @Qonvex620, maybe you can add cawangan_ppk into hidden field..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that the array you passed to the serve does not contain cawangan_ppk key, that is why it returned Undefined index. please provide a cawangan_ppk  name in your form.

I think on this select tag you had missed it.

```
// change this
<select class="form-control" type="text" name="cawangan" id="cawangan" maxlength="12" placeholder="bahagian" required /></select> 

// to this
<select class="form-control" type="text" name="cawangan_ppk" id="cawangan" maxlength="12" placeholder="bahagian" required /></select>
```

You can then do this declaration to be sure you have to return an error even cawangan_ppk exists or not.

```
$input_cawangan_ppk =  $_POST["cawangan_ppk"] ? trim($_POST["cawangan_ppk"]) : '';
```

Comment: That would also return unidentified index. The name should be the same on how you access it in `$_POST` array it should be also `cawangan_ppk`

Comment: I'm just telling that line is his error,